# Is the bride in "Pride and Bridezilla" in "Made In Heaven" web-series inspired from real life?

Tags: made-in-heaven

In the Amazon prime series "Made In Heaven", Season 1 Episode 8, there is there plot-line of a girl who does a wedding video song with her BFFs. I couldn't help but draw parallels to a real Indian bride (Amisha Bharadwaj's wedding video) who became viral 2 years back who did a Sia's "Cheap Thrills" rendition.

Was this plotline (for the wedding song, and not the bratty character, Tarana Ali) inspired from this ?

Comment: People doing this way before that cheap thrill video and even now pre-wedding video shoot is a thing

Comment: I do get that, but that one specific video which i mentioned with the bride is so uncannily the same as in the show (the clothes, the best friends, the makeup bit, dancing, and the bride too). I haven't for sure seen another bride in a similar video which makes me wonder if  the song bit was inspired from the real bride. Its like as soon as i saw the episode, the first thing that came to my mind was that one video with that bride

Comment: ohh ok, fair enough, Not seen the show so can't say much